# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la contraseña de un usuario en Django?

Tags: python, django

Con frecuencia me ocurre que hago cambios en la contraseña de Django o bien recupero backups para correrlo en local, etc. Y siempre me pasa que cuando quiero acceder a Django Admin no recuerdo la contraseña.

Para cambiar la contraseña de un usuario utilizo a veces la consola:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.get(username='mi_usuario')
user.set_password('mi_contraseña')
user.save()
```

Pero resulta un poco tedioso hacerlo siempre así. ¿Hay alguna forma más rápida?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sí, con `manage.py` puedes hacerlo:

```
manage.py changepassword <nombre_usuario>
```

Está documentado en [Changing passwords](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/stable/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords) <sub>en inglés</sub>.

Comment: Excelente pregunta / respuesta!, siempre lo había realizado de la manera más tediosa y nunca se me ocurrió hacerlo con manage.py, bueno cada día se aprende algo nuevo :)

Comment: @Riaven cuánto me alegra que sea útil a otra gente! A mí me sorprendió descubrirlo y me dije "pues vamos a explicarlo" :)